# How to make a list float to the right in a div

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am trying to set the list to float to the right inside a div but it's not working.
Following is the html code,

```
<div class="topdiv">
    <header>MakeItWork</header>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Shop</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

And this is the css I am trying to make it work

```
.topdiv{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.topdiv header{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  font-size: xxx-large;
  margin-left: 5%;
}


.navigation{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
  float: right;
}


.navigation li{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

edit: My intention is to keep the header text (MakeItWork) to the left of the page and the list(containing home, content and shop as list items) to the right of the page.[Something as shown in the provided picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJJnK.png)

Comment: *but it's not working* is not a helpful problem description. Downvoted.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you try to do, or You have to write what you expect exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:right` to `.navigation li` and add `justify-content:space-between` to `.topdiv` to align title and list and different ends.

Note: I hope that you are making a navigation menu. Therefore further I added `list-style: none` rule to `.navigation`. Please consider that it is an extra rule that I've added.

```css
.topdiv{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topdiv header{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  font-size: xxx-large;
  margin-left: 5%;
}


.navigation{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}


.navigation li{
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="topdiv">
    <header>MakeItWork</header>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Shop</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `justify-content:space-between`, and `float` doesn't work with `flex`

```css
.topdiv{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between
}

.topdiv header{
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  font-size: xxx-large;
  margin-left: 5%;
}


.navigation{
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}


.navigation li{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topdiv">
    <header>MakeItWork</header>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Shop</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.topdiv {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.topdiv header {
  font-size: xxx-large;
}

.navigation {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation li {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="topdiv">
  <header>MakeItWork</header>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Shop</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```